# Use both iText7 and iText 2.17

Tags: itext, itextpdf

Our Project has been using iText 2.17 for a long time. Now we would like to add digital signature to our pdfs and we prefer to use iText7. Can both iText < 5.3 and 5.3+ libraries used together? Will there be a problem in class loader or all the packages different from its predecessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question starts well, but then gets confusing.

- You can use iText 2 in combination with iText 5.
- You can use iText 2 in combination with iText 7.
- You can use iText 5 in combination with iText 7.

One can't state that you can use versions < 5.3 and versions >= 5.3 together. For instance: you can't use 5.0.0 and 5.5.9 together because they have the same major version number. You will have clashes in package names.

Summarized: all major versions have different package names, so that you can use major versions next to each other without clashes.

Comment: @Cybermonk Be aware, though, that you should use security related stuff (digital signing, ...) with only one of those versions because the different iText versions rely on different versions of BouncyCastle (in particular the iText 2.x versions rely on old ones) which can not coexist in the same classpath.

Comment: I have a that might be related to what you said.                      ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest(); throws class not found exception. I have bouncycastle bcprov-ext-jdk15on-154 in my classPath and I am using iText 5.5. Are they compatible?

Comment: iText 5 uses BouncyCastle 1.49, as you can see in the iText POM. https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/itext/pom.xml